# Opentk unproject how to use to get a ray

Tags: c#, opentk

Hi i am trying to make a `GetRayFrom2D` function in my camera class as in mouse coordinates to `PickingRay` in opentk in csharp. This is the code:

```cs
Vector3 A = CameraPosition;
Vector3 B = Vector3.Unproject(CameraPosition, _2D.X, _2D.Y, Screen.Width, Screen.Height, 1f, 10000f, ViewProjection.Inverted());
Ray3D R = new Ray3D(A,B);
return R;
```

can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong please

Comment: you didn't mention why your code is not working - what result do you get?

Comment: The more mouse coordinates are away from the center the more ray is off the direction it should be